# Tortoise and hare algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I was reading Tortoise and hare algorithm from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare). I am wondering whether the python pseudocode is wrong. It seems to fail for the array: `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ....]` as at the very beginning, the two values meet and the algorithm continues to find the start of the cycle which is doomed to failure. 
I understand that there is condition of `i ≥ μ`, should this constraint be added to the code for finding the start of the cycle? 
If this constraint is added, should the algorithm terminate and return no cycle found when failed or continue for another iteration? Since what if the input is `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, ....]` ? 
How does this algorithm guarantee that at the first meeting point, both pointers are inside some cycles?

Comment: So what happens when you run the code?

Comment: I have not implemented it but I believe it is going to be infinite loop.

Comment: so how about implementing it. Or do you really think that an algorithm which is more than 50 years old is wrong and has not been unnoticed? Moreover it will work with any multiplier. 2 is selected because it will allow to detect the cycle in the fastest way.

Comment: The algorithm doesn't work on arrays but rather iterated sequences. Your counterexample is not an iterated sequence since you have f(2) = 2 and f(2) = 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tortoise and hare algorithm runs two pointers, one at offset `i` and the other at offset `2i`, both one-based, so initially `1` and `2`, and is meant to detect cycles in linked-list-style data structures.

And, just to be clear, it compares the *pointers* rather than data values they point to, I'm unsure whether you understand that so, on the off-chance you didn't, I just thought I'd mention it.

The initial start point is to have the tortoise on the first element and the hare on the second (assuming they exist of course - if they don't, no loop is possible), so it's incorrect to state that they're equal at the start. The pointer value can only ever become equal if the hare cycles and therefore catches the tortoise from behind.

Comment: I missed the pointer comparison part. I misunderstood it for value comparison. As for someone mentioned on the comments saying it does not work on arrays but iterated sequences. Is this true?

Comment: @Ra1nWarden: yes, at least on the "does not work on arrays" front. A normal array, by definition, cannot have cycles, since it consists on `N` consecutive things (I say normal because you could _treat_ an array as a linked list by encoding the data and next index into each element, but that's not the normal use case).